# How to get number of the same members in mdx?

Tags: sql, mdx, cube, olap-cube

I would like to determine the number of particular weekdays (e.g. Mondays, Tuesdays, and so on....) between two dates. I thought something like the following should work, but member returns 1.

What have i done wrong?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER measures.NumberOfSameWeekDays AS 
    Count([Dim Date].[Day Of Week].CurrentMember) 
SELECT 
  measures.NumberOfSameWeekDays ON COLUMNS
 ,[Dim Date].[Day Of Week].[Day Of Week] ON ROWS
FROM [test]
WHERE 
  (
    [Dim Client].[Common Client UID].&[{ED8822E7-2873-4388-BC3A-CC553D939FC4}]
   ,
    [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20150701] : [Dim Date].[Date Int].&[20150731]
  );
```

Comment: this will always return 1: `Count( <some hierarchy used on rows>.currentmember)` ...because 1 member is _currently_ in the context of the resultset.

Comment: can you give a code example?

Comment: `.CurrentMember` is a function that returns the member on the row - if a row has one member on it, then it returns 1. No example required. In your script for the row that says Tuesday the `.Currentmember` function is counting how many times it has Tuesday on the Tuesday row .... 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proof of what is happening:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER measures.NumberOfSameWeekDays AS 
    Count([Date].[Day of Week].CurrentMember) 
  MEMBER measures.WeekDayCurrentMem AS 
    [Date].[Day of Week].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
SELECT 
  {
    measures.NumberOfSameWeekDays
   ,measures.WeekDayCurrentMem
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[Date].[Day of Week].[Day of Week] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050101]
  : 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050116];
```

Here is the result of the above:

[image]

Here is a solution to the above behaviour:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER measures.NumberOfSameWeekDays AS 
    Count
    (
      (EXISTING 
        [Date].[Day of Week].CurrentMember * [Date].[Calendar].[Date])
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    measures.NumberOfSameWeekDays
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[Date].[Day of Week].[Day of Week] ON ROWS
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050101]
  : 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20050131];
```

This returns the following:

[image]

---

A simplified version of Sourav's answer - although still rather complex - and potentially slow as it uses Generate which is iterative:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER Measures.CountOfDays AS 
    Generate
    (
      (EXISTING 
        [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS)
     ,[Date].[Day of Week]
     ,ALL
    ).Count 
SELECT 
  Measures.CountOfDays ON 0
 ,[Date].[Day of Week].[Day of Week].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
WHERE 
  [Date].[Calendar].&[2005] : [Date].[Calendar].&[2006];
```

Comment: Let me revise my answer..Deleting it for now.

Comment: Nothing. Actually yours is better I feel. Added my answer just to satisfy my initial understanding of the solution.

Comment: INTERESTINGLY, if in the `Generate`, you replace `[Date].[Day of Week]` with `[Date].[Day of Week].[Day of Week]`, you get completely different solutions! Weird. I guess in the later case, [Date].[Day of Week].CURRENTMEMBER or `EXISTING` is implicit. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Adventure Works version:

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.CountOfDays  AS
GENERATE
    (
     EXISTING [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS,
     EXISTING [Date].[Day of Week].[Day of Week].MEMBERS
     ,ALL
    ).COUNT


SELECT Measures.CountOfDays ON 0
,[Date].[Day of Week].[Day of Week].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]  
WHERE [Date].[Calendar].&[2005]: [Date].[Calendar].&[2006]
```

The `GENERATE` part gets all the days of weeks in current context and based on whatever filter you might have.

Comment: no probs - I added a simpler version of the above to my answer - with a small health warning about `Generate`.

Comment: here is one for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32441887/mtd-without-using-the-mtd-function

Comment: Done..now gimme my cookie ;)