# MTD without using the MTD function

Tags: mdx

This is our current `MTD` calculation:

```
  MEMBER [Time Calculations].[Time Calculations].[Calculate MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      MTD([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember)
     ,[Time Calculations].[Time Calculations].[Current Value]
    )
```

I've seen somewhere along the way a MTD calculation that uses the range operator `:`. The following will be a sum from the start of time:

```
  MEMBER [Time Calculations].[Time Calculations].[Calculate MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      null: [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember
     ,[Time Calculations].[Time Calculations].[Current Value]
    )
```

Can anyone remember how to adjust the above so that it is a `MTD` calculation?

Comment: What exactly is `[Time Calculations].[Time Calculations].[Current Value]`? What is the purpose of this dimension-hierarchy?

Comment: Is `[Date - Calendar Month]` a natural or user defined hierarchy and if yes, what are the levels?

Comment: it's user defined hierarchy. Levels are as follows `(All) | [Calendar Year] | [Calendar Half Year] | [Calendar Quarter] | [Calendar Month] | [Calendar Day]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `[Date - Calendar Month]` is similar to `Calendar` hierarchy of Adventure Works, following might work for you:

```
  MEMBER [Time Calculations].[Time Calculations].[Calculate MTD] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember.firstsibling
       : 
      [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].CurrentMember
     ,[Time Calculations].[Time Calculations].[Current Value]
    )
```

Comment: pretty pretty - I suspect it is fast too.

Comment: it is quick too: thanks Sourav, help appreciated: I was having a mental block on this one for some reason.